# Dashboard is not refreshing properly

Tags: reporting, dashboard, refresh

I am surprised why this is happening to one of my client. He complained me that his dashboard is not refreshing and showing this error :

> "The dashboard can not be displayed because the source report has
>   exceeded the time limit".

But when i checked from my location its working fine.

Is location plays a role in this ? or there is something more i need to check ?

I have also added more filters in report but the issue is, at the same time my client is getting error and when i checked by login into his account then dashboard works fine.

Can anyone help me to resolve this ?

I really appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible root cause is described [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004480&language=en_US).

> Resolution 
>   This will occur if the source report takes longer than 10
>   minutes to complete, as the report will be cancelled. The report will
>   need to be optimized for better performance.

As mentioned above as well, identify if there is any difference in data sets if you and client are different Salesforce users. If not, then you should look at optimising your report by filtering out data based on various parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to the running user of the dashboard. The running user of the dashboard may be seeing more data than what you are seeing. Due to which the report may be timing out when run as him/her, while it runs fine for you.

If possible login as the running user and try to run the report.

For the report timing out, it would help to add more filters and specify shorter date ranges in the report.